# get values from ANY type Object

Tags: apex, json, callout, map, list

I'm having issues trying to extract values from object list, this is the flow:

- button gets clicked
- click calls a callout function
- get response from `response.getBody()`

at this point, I have two options:

1. Use JSON2Apex, that for some reason always return: "Apex Type unsupported in JSON: Object

```
if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
       //Where, TicketJson is JSON2Apex class
       TicketJson ticketResponse = TicketJson.parse(response.getBody());
       System.debug(ticketResponse);
```

2. Use JSON.deserializeUntyped(), this my favorite approach, but when I manage to reach the Object List that I need, I'm unable to get it's Object values as MAP

```
if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
    Map<String, Object> obj = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
    Object ticketTypeData = obj.get('ticket_group');
    Map<String, Object> TicketData = (Map<String, Object>)ticketTypeData;
    List<Object> Data = (List<Object>) TicketData.get('_data');
```

Any help is welcome.

Best regards.

JSON2Apex class

```
public class TicketJson {

public Integer x_total {get;set;} // in json: _total
public Event_template event_template {get;set;} 
public Ticket_group ticket_group {get;set;} 
public Ticket_type ticket_type {get;set;} 

public class Ticket_group {
    public Integer x_count {get;set;} // in json: _count
    public List<Data_Z> x_data {get;set;} // in json: _data
    public Integer x_total {get;set;} // in json: _total

    public Ticket_group(JSONParser parser) {
        while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
            if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                String text = parser.getText();
                if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                    if (text == '_count') {
                        x_count = parser.getIntegerValue();
                    } else if (text == '_data') {
                        x_data = arrayOfData_Z(parser);
                    } else if (text == '_total') {
                        x_total = parser.getIntegerValue();
                    } else {
                        System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Ticket_group consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                        consumeObject(parser);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

JSON Example

```
{
"ticket_group": {
    "_count": 21,
    "_data": [
      {
        "_rank": 1,
        "additional_info_spec": null,
        "admission_end_offset": "2h",
        "admission_start_offset": "-10m",
        "capacity": -1,
        "description": "",
        "duration": null,
        "duration_new": null,
        "event_template_id": "4549294f-bc7a-1679-7797-90c5a9180c90",
        "exclude_from_event_capacity": false,
        "handler": "tickets",
        "hidden_type": "public_browsable",
        "id": "0e038e0e-24f2-5186-3c6c-adae2727d29d",
        "max_redemptions": 1,
        "max_tickets_per_order": 15,
        "member_role_id": null,
        "min_tickets_per_order": 1,
        "name": "Free Admission by PNC",
        "oversell_capacity": 0,
        "portal_id": "605f5cc3-3892-4c6f-bed0-4910cecd82b0",
        "sales_end_offset": null,
        "sales_start_offset": null,
        "sells_out_event": false,
        "start_policy": "immediate"
      },
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Could you please [edit] your post to provide an example of the JSON you are working with and your parsing class?

Comment: @DavidReed, Thank you for your answer, Post has been updated with the JSON2Apex class for the JSON piece , let say that _data, is a List of Those objects